# haproxy redirect to Tomcat app

Tags: tomcat, haproxy

I`m using Haproxy 1.6 for my project.

I have a tomcat aplication, which placed at `tomcat-node.local/MyApp`

I've create a dns `somedomainname` and want to redirect all requests to `tomcat-node.local/MyApp`

my haproxy conf:

```
frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
    default_backend application-backend

frontend https-in
    bind *:443 ssl crt /pathtopem/key.pem
    acl portal2 hdr_dom(host) -i somedomainname

    mode http
    rspadd Strict-Transport-Security:\ max-age=31536000;\ includeSubDomains;\ preload
    rsprep ^Set-Cookie:\ (.*) Set-Cookie:\ \1;\ Secure if { ssl_fc }
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
    use_backend portal2-backend if portal2
    default_backend application-backend

backend portal2-backend
    mode http
    balance leastconn
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor
    stats uri /admin?stat
    stats enable
    cookie JSESSIONID prefix
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }


    server node1.domain.local 192.168.0.1:8080 maxconn 32 check inter 5000 cookie node1.domain.local
    server node2.domain.local 192.168.0.2:8080 maxconn 32 check inter 5000 cookie node2.domain.local
```

This conf works perfectly. 
But I need to specify `MyApp` in url path to get my aplication: `http://somedomainname/MyApp -->  http://tomcat-node.local/MyApp`

I need to redirect all requests like that:
`http://somedomainname/%Someurl% -->  http://tomcat-node.local/MyApp/%SomeUrl%`

How can I do that?

Comment: You can't do that by HAProxy.